# How to instatiate datasource from list of datasources?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring.

I have multiple databases but any given time one database is open depending on which database user select. So I have a bean defined as below. So my question is how do I instantiate the datasource user select and use it in my class if I use below given bean. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
  <bean id="dataSources" class="java.util.TreeMap">
    <constructor-arg>
      <map>
        <entry key="dp1www" value-ref="dataSourceDp1www" />
        <entry key="dp2www" value-ref="dataSourceDp2www" />
        <entry key="sp0www" value-ref="dataSourceSp0www" />
        <entry key="sp1www" value-ref="dataSourceSp1www" />
        <entry key="sp2www" value-ref="dataSourceSp2www" />
      </map>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <bean id="dataSourceDp1www" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"> 
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@sf1-hab-ppb-ww.home.com:1525/dp1www1.home.com" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="username" value="select" />
    <property name="password" value="######" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="dataSourceDp2www" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@sf1-hbl-ppb-ww.home.com:1525/dp2www1.home.com" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="username" value="select" />
    <property name="password" value="######" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="dataSourceSp0www" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@sf1-hbl-ppb-ww.home.com:1525/sp0www1.home.com" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="username" value="select" />
    <property name="password" value="######" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="dataSourceSp1www" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@sf1-hab-ppb-ww.home.com:1525/sp1www1.home.com" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="username" value="select" />
    <property name="password" value="######" />
  </bean>
```

Comment: I am getting null in dataSource when I try to get the datasource  for some reason.

DataSource dataSource = dataSources.get("dp1www");

Comment: Thanks Branislav. It is working now. Seems like I had 
<context:annotation-config> missing in spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `@Autowired` annotation to inject `TreeMap` instance:

```
@Autowired
private TreeMap<String, DataSource> dataSources;
....
DataSource dataSource = dataSources.get("dp1www");
```

or you can directly inject specific data source without even creating `TreeMap`

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSourceDp1www;
```